# Laravel artisan migrate problem SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mysql failed: Name or service not known

Tags: laravel, docker, migration, sails.js, laravel-artisan

When I run ./vendor/bin/sail artisan migrate. I am getting this kind of error.

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mysql failed: Name or service not known (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = online_shop and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:760
    756▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    757▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    758▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    759▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 760▕             throw new QueryException(
    761▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    762▕             );
    763▕         }
    764▕     }

      +39 vendor frames 
  40  artisan:35
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

This is my docker-compose file

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.2
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.2/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
            - '${VITE_PORT:-5173}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - redis
            - meilisearch
            - mailhog
            - selenium
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
            - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    phpmyadmin:
        depends_on:
            - mysql
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        environment:
            - PMA_HOST=mysql
            - PMA_PORT=3306
        networks:
            - sail
        ports:
            - 8001:80
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sail-redis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    meilisearch:
        image: 'getmeili/meilisearch:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MEILISEARCH_PORT:-7700}:7700'
        volumes:
            - 'sail-meilisearch:/meili_data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "wget", "--no-verbose", "--spider",  "http://localhost:7700/health"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    mailhog:
        image: 'mailhog/mailhog:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_PORT:-1025}:1025'
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025'
        networks:
            - sail
    selenium:
        image: 'selenium/standalone-chrome'
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        volumes:
            - '/dev/shm:/dev/shm'
        networks:
            - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mysql:
        driver: local
    sail-redis:
        driver: local
    sail-meilisearch:
        driver: local
```

This is my .env file

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:s6gzMFdbiF7ITe8NvF+/cGmVHic20oKd+W+cg7W+ugI=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=online_shop
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=memcached

REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="hello@example.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_HOST=
PUSHER_PORT=443
PUSHER_SCHEME=https
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
VITE_PUSHER_HOST="${PUSHER_HOST}"
VITE_PUSHER_PORT="${PUSHER_PORT}"
VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME="${PUSHER_SCHEME}"
VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"

SCOUT_DRIVER=meilisearch
MEILISEARCH_HOST=http://meilisearch:7700
```

I reinstalled docker twice but it didn't work. Change DB_HOST in .env file to localhost or http://127.0.0.1/ it didn't work too. My previous project was working in docker, now the problems started

Comment: You must use `mysql` as your host, because that is where you have the DB, still not having, I honestly have no idea, make sure you have everything running

Comment: @matiaslauriti Works in docker without errors, I can work with the database through phpmyadmin, but artisan migrate doesn't work. Please provide specific instructions.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the team helped me

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

I use Laravel sail

```
./vendor/bin/sail artisan migrate:fresh
```